# Notepad++ set delimiter between text

Tags: notepad++

Struggling to find a way to delimit this as the common symbols you would use to delimit are reused throughout the different strings. I want to break a line at each occurrence of TRNDATA.

Example:
[image: Example]

Example of the output wanted:
[image: Example]

Comment: You want to add a delimiter - for instance a tab character or maybe ```|``` - to the file, or actually use find and replace to break lines before every ```{"TRNDATA":```?

Comment: Could you endeavour to post text as text, rather than pictures. Pictures of text cannot be indexed by google or read by software for the sight-impaired. Copy/paste, select then Ctrl/K to format as 'code'

Comment: Everytime TRNDATA appears to break it to a new line. Doesnt need actually replace anything.

Comment: Apologies am unable to paste as text. I posted another picture showing what I would want it to look like.

Comment: [Please post your data as text, not image.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/372239). I don't understand why you're unable to paste! `Ctrl+C` then `Ctrl+V` !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Replace window, with *Regular expression* selected, Find:

```
(.)({"TRNDATA":)
```

Replace with:

```
\1\r\n\2
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This will replace all spaces between a comma and `{"TRNDATA":` with a linebreak.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<=,)\h*(?={"TRNDATA":)`
- Replace with: `\n` or `\r\n` depending on platform
- **TICK** *Match case*
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=,)              # positive lookbehind, make sure we have a comma before
\h*                 # 0 or more horizontal spaces
(?={"TRNDATA":)     # positive lookahead, make sure we have "{"TRNDATA":" after
```